# How can I log the creation of Exchange 2003 and 2010 mailboxes?

Tags: exchange, audit

We are trying to acquire a new certificate/label. In order to get this certificate/label we need to monitor the creation of mailboxes in Microsoft Exchange.

We are currently using Microsoft ACS (Audit Collection Services), but if a mailbox is created we are not able to get it in the logs. There is nothing in the `evntvwr`.

Is there a way to log the creation of a new mailbox in Exchange 2003/2010?

Comment: Microsoft Ops Manager can monitor that successfully: http://www.toolzz.com/?p=102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Exchange 2010 try to increase the logging level for Account Management. From management console -> Server Configuration -> Mailbox -> Manage Diagnostic Logging Properties -> MXExchangeAL -> Account Management -> set to high. Then create a mailbox and check in Application Event log